# truncate and insert in stored procedure mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Can someone tell me why my syntax is wrong?

I set the delimiter to $$ do prevent ; to be a problem. I dont want to create the tables a truncate is fine.

```
DELIMITER $$
create procedure create persistent_views
begin

truncate table vwt_total_overview_last3days;
truncate table vwt_total_overview_last30days:
truncate table vwt_total_overview_last7days;
truncate table vwt_total_overview_lastday;

insert into vwt_total_overview_last3days
select * from total_overview_last3days;

insert into vwt_total_overview_last30days
select * from total_overview_last30days;

insert into vwt_total_overview_last7days
select * from total_overview_last7days;

insert into vwt_total_overview_lastday
select * from total_overview_lastday;

END $$
```

I am getting:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'create persistent_views begin truncate table vwt_total_overview_last3days; trun' at line 1
```

i changed the statement to the following, but it did not work either (tried with and without parens and AS )

```
DELIMITER $$
create procedure persistent_views() AS 
begin

truncate table vwt_total_overview_last3days;
truncate table vwt_total_overview_last30days:
truncate table vwt_total_overview_last7days;
truncate table vwt_total_overview_lastday;

insert into vwt_total_overview_last3days
select * from total_overview_last3days;

insert into vwt_total_overview_last30days
select * from total_overview_last30days;

insert into vwt_total_overview_last7days
select * from total_overview_last7days;

insert into vwt_total_overview_lastday
select * from total_overview_lastday;

END $$
```

Comment: what is the problem you are getting

Comment: i edited the start post.

Comment: change this line create procedure create persistent_views to create procedure create_persistent_views and you should be through

Answer (score 0):

You have used the `CREATE` word twice. Just remove the second one. This might solve your prob. After that a pair of paranthesis and `AS` keyword after that.

Comment: Unfortuneatly not. it just changed the error messag slightly to #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'begin truncate table vwt_total_overview_last3days; truncate table vwt_total_ove' at line 2

Comment: did you try adding parenthesis.

Comment: yes. problem is, this is my first SP on mysql and i really dont know what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Ok i solved it by myself. One semi colon, was actually a colon ....

Correct syntax was:

```
DELIMITER $$
create procedure persistentViews() 
BEGIN
truncate table vwt_total_overview_last3days;
truncate table vwt_total_overview_last30days;
truncate table vwt_total_overview_last7days;
truncate table vwt_total_overview_lastday;

insert into vwt_total_overview_last3days
select * from total_overview_last3days;

insert into vwt_total_overview_last30days
select * from total_overview_last30days;

insert into vwt_total_overview_last7days
select * from total_overview_last7days;

insert into vwt_total_overview_lastday
select * from total_overview_lastday;
END $$
```